# Discord API error : cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was following a YouTube tutorial on how to program a discord bot, and I came across the infamous error "cannot send an empty message" while trying to send an embed. Here is my code :

main.js :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const prefix = '!';
const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Picobot is ready for use!');
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if (command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command === 'pong') {
        client.commands.get('pong').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command === 'permissions') {
        client.commands.get('permissions').execute(message, args);
    }

    if (command === 'embed') {
        client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
});
```

embed.js :

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'embed',
    description: 'Embeds',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#304281')
        .setTitle('Rules')
        .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ')
        .setDescription('This is a test embed')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'Rule 1', value: 'Placeholder 1'},
            {name: 'Rule 2', value: 'Placeholder 2'},
            {name: 'Rule 3', value: 'Placeholder 3'},
        )
        .setImage('https://images.radio-canada.ca/q_auto,w_960/v1/ici-info/16x9/rick-astley-videoclip-never-gonna-give-you-up.png');
        message.channel.send({ newEmbed:newEmbed });
    }
}
```

I have seen a number of other people having this error, the only solutions I've found and tried so far were to change `message.channel.send({ newEmbed:newEmbed })` to `message.channel.send(newEmbed)`, but the same error still pops up. I haven't seen any answered problems about this error in 2021, so I figured I'd shoot my shot here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Transitioning from v12 to v13 we have encountered another weary change that makes no sense to some users

```js
// message.channel.send(newEmbed) does not work anymore
message.channel.send({
    embeds: [newEmbed]
});
// The above is the way to go!
```

Another change: the message event listener:

```
client.on("message", () => {})
```

is depreciated and has been changed to [`messageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I'll make sure to check the documentation from now on.

Answer (score 0):

In v13 sending embeds is structured as such:

```js
message.channel.send({ embeds: [newEmbed] });
```

[Embeds - Discord.JS](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html)